# SQL Server circular data query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple table of 3 records like this below:

```
ChildID | ParentID | Name
--------------------------
   1    |   null   | ABC
   2    |   null   | DEF
   3    |    1     | GHI
```

What i need is a **query** that basically lists out the name and the parent name. In case of null it should return no parent, something of this sort:

```
ChildID |   Name   | Parent_Name
--------------------------------
   1    |   ABC    | no parent
   2    |   DEF    | no parent
   3    |   GHI    | ABC
```

Since I'm new to SQL server I'm not really sure how to approach this question. I have tried to search but in vain. Any comments would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `left outer join` will do the job. try this

```
CREATE TABLE #tttt
  (
     childid  INT,
     parentid INT,
     name     VARCHAR(50)
  )

INSERT INTO #tttt
VALUES      (1,NULL,'ABC'),
            (2,NULL,'DEF'),
            (3,1,'GHI')

SELECT a.childid,
       a.name,
       Isnull(b.name, 'No parent') AS Parent_Name
FROM   #tttt a
       LEFT JOIN #tttt b
              ON b.childid = a.parentid
```

**OUTPUT**

```
childid name    Parent_Name
------  ----    ----------- 
1       ABC     No parent
2       DEF     No parent
3       GHI     ABC
```

Comment: cheers mate. The ISNULL() function was the main stumbling block